# How to open the files of the repository from Visual Studio Code in Git Bash?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, git-bash

I cloned the http link of the repository and I gave the `cd` to the repository name. And after that I wanted to open the files of that repository from VS Code. I tried to open the VS code in Git Bash by typing the following queries, but none of them worked.

Queries I have tried

1. `start "" "Microsoft VS Code"`
2. `start "" "Microsoft VS Code" .`
3. `Microsoft VS Code .`
4. `/Microsoft VS Code`
5. `start "" "Visual Studio Code" .`
6. `start Code.exe`
7. `start Code.exe .`
8. `code.exe`
9. `code.exe .`

Comment: First set the VS Code as the default editor in git config file then use the command `code .` to open the file(s) in the editor.  Reference: https://github.com/ArunRaj6/git-advanced-commands#config-editor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally tried the following query. And **it worked**.

Just type `Code .` and the VS Code window will pop up including the files of the repository.